# Build failed with an exception - I have tons of questions

Tags: android

After being kicked off of reddit and told to come here, I have some massive questions.

I just started to code, I am trying to release my first app. However, right as I went to submit it, I messed up and everything is crazy now! So I will start at the beginning:

I am making an app that lets you shuffle between ideas on what to build in minecraft. Each tap brings up a new random idea - that is all. It is super simple, I am keeping it that way since it is my first ever app. Now, I had it working, I have every drawing I need for the app. But as I went to submit the app to actually publish it, my .apk file was invalid. I was using the test version, which wasn't allowed to be used in the submission.

I then followed a guide that instructed me to delete my Gradle and .Gradle folders, and apparently android studio was supposed to regenerate them and fix it. Well, that did not happen. What happened was that my 'Android' folder in Android Studio became empty - there is now an app folder with nothing in it, and a Gradle Scripts section with various files that I had not seen before. The majority of my file names are red or orange.

Now, most of if not all of my code is still here. However, it says that the Gradle project sync failed, and I don't know what that means. I can no longer find out the source of these files, as in, there is no manifests or java folder located within my 'Android' heading. I don't know what to do to get it back. I had almost everything taken care of, and I am certain there is a simple way to get it all back. I did not make a VCS at the time, since nobody ever told me I should. Like I said, I am new at making apps. I still have the folder with what appears to be every single bit of code I have made so far.

If you can help me I will be extremely grateful. I have spent almost three weeks working on this, and it would be horrible to see it all go down the drain over one simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a new project and adding your source files, dependencies and resources to it?